# Nodejs read JSON data from a http request chunk

Tags: json, node.js, rest

I am using Jira API's to get data on single tickets. I have successfully setup a http GET request to the server and can display the data to the console however I ideally need to get certain properties from the data which is in JSON format.

When I try to read the properties I just get undefined.

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
res.setEncoding('utf8');
res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);         // This displays the JSON
    console.log('endSTATUS: ' + chunk.id); // This shows up undefined
});
```

The data is in [this](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/issue-getIssue) format from jira API for reference.
The first console log in the res successfully displays all the data from the chunk.
The second one is:

```
endSTATUS: undefined
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to get the body after the data stream finish. Like this:

```
        var body = '';
        response.on('data', function(d) {
            body += d;
        });
        response.on('end', function() {

            // Data reception is done, do whatever with it!
            var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log('endSTATUS: ' + parsed.id);
        });
```

Comment: Still works in 2021. Thanks for sharing! .on('end'... )

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are parsing the response data as JSON. I think you may want something like `var data = JSON.parse(chunk);`, and reference the chunk data as `data.value`.

```
res.on('data', function (chunk) {
var data = JSON.parse(chunk);
console.log('BODY: ' + data);         
console.log('endSTATUS: ' + data.id); 
});
```

Comment: Great that worked, couldn't find anything on the documentation on chunks, thanks!

Comment: Happens to me all the time, happy coding!