# How to extract From, To, Subject from chunks in Node

Tags: node.js, chunks

I am currently working to extract data such as to, from, subject etc. from chunks.
Here is my code

```
var data = [];
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            data.push(chunk);

        }).on('end', function () {
            var buffer = Buffer.concat(data);
            console.log(buffer.toString());
            var result = buffer.toString();
        });
```

But when I try to get data to from as "result.from" , I get "undefined" &
I try to parse result as JSON.parse(result) , I get

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

How can I retrieve the data?

The chunks looks like

```
<Buffer 2d 2d 78 59 7a 5a 59 0d 0a 43 6f ... >
```

console.log buffer.toString() looks like

--xYzZY
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="headers"

Received: ................
 Received: ...........................
 Received: ...................

```
>  MIME-Version: 1.0  References: ............  In-Reply-To: ........ 
> From: ........  Date: Mon, 20 Apr 2020 19:52:59 +0530  Message-ID:
> .............  Subject: ..........  To: ..............  Content-Type:
> ...............    --xYzZY
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey not sure if you've given this a try but:
[Nodejs read JSON data from a http request chunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320987/nodejs-read-json-data-from-a-http-request-chunk)

has a verified answer of:

> Try to get the body after the data stream finish. Like this:
>
> ```
>     var body = '';
>     response.on('data', function(d) {
>         body += d;
>     });
>     response.on('end', function() {
>
>         // Data reception is done, do whatever with it!
>         var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
>         console.log('endSTATUS: ' + parsed.id);
>     });
> ```

Comment: I had already written above whenever I write JSON.parse, I get SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Hey, not sure if you've gotten this resolved or not but it looks like in your code posted, your using an array for that buffer data, have you tried using var body = ''; and adding it to the string like in the reponse.on(''data')? Can you add in your code to show the JSON.parse?

Comment: Yes I have tried both by using array & string. But whenever I write JSON.parse I get same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
const chunks = []; 
const zlib = require('zlib');
res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk)
});   
res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('-----end----')

     const content = zlib.unzipSync(Buffer.concat(chunks))
     console.log(content.toString());

})
```